# A tool to test website speed on local host

Tags: web-development, performance-analysis

I know google's pagespeed tool provides a good analysis of website's performance. Sadly, it requires accessing a URL.

I don't want to do that as my app is intranet. I want to test the performance locally. But, I can't seem to find any offline tool that can load a page from localhost and check how well it performs.

Is there any such tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Chrome as your browser. Under the *Development Tools*, use *Network*.

You can even mimic your bandwidth, e.g. throttle to the speed of a 500 MB GPRS connection.

Comment: That app works only on ie that too in compatibility mode (thanks to xml files for data cache). :/ Adding browser compatibility is a plan long way away for now. Can I do it in IE as well?

Comment: Actually it is there in IE as well. It lists total time for each file separately, no sum, but that is far better to be honest.

Comment: I need a tool that might be able to identify the problem areas. That network section is a start, as it tells me the actual performance. It just doesn't tell me where to start fixing it.

Comment: The same feature is available in Firefox.